# Cant see controls inside User Control in the VisualTreeHelper

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls, wpf-controls

I have UserControl in wpf 4.0 which contains buttons , labels , textboxes etc....
I want to loop those controls and when I get a buuton , I want to take it's name and save it to my list .  Basically , all I want to do is to create a Names_list of all my buttons in the UserControl.

I have a method that iterates all the controls and if it finds a button , it saves it's name -

```
  public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
        {
            // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
            Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

            Button _button = childVisual as Button;
            if (_button != null)
            {
                Class_Button _newButtonClass = new Class_Button();
                if (_button.Name != null)
                {
                    _newButtonClass.ButtonName = _button.Name; 
                }
                ButtonsList.Add(_newButtonClass);
            }

            // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
            EnumVisual(childVisual);

        }
    }
```

I always get an empty list.
When I enter in to the code by debugging it and I watch the VisualTree of my UserControl , I see all the Panels and GroupBoxes and Grids but I dont see buttons , labels and texboxes although every control has a x:Name and every control is x:FieldModifier="public". This is very odd....And I cant understand the reason for that as well as how to solve this problem... 
can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?
thanks

Comment: When are you calling EnumVisual()? Are you sure the template has been applied at that point?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I create my MainWindow , which contains the UserControl and after it is shown I call the function which gets the buttons list by clicking a menuItem.....and by that point I can see the UserControl inside my MainWindow....

Comment: It doesn't mean the UserControl is already loaded. It may be in the middle of the process at the point your code enters that method. Try calling that method, say, in some temporary button click event handler

Comment: @EvAlex You are right....the user control is placed on one of the tab items and only after i open the tab and actually see the user control , it's buttons appear in the buttons list....I cant understand why the panels are generated and the controls inside are not.....thank you for you help :)

Comment: Elements are initialized in a bottom-up manner so the buttons should have been initialized before their containers. And before rendering. How do you add those buttons to the UserControl? Not in XAML, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)
or [WPF Inspector](http://wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html)
to examine the visual tree of your control.
If these tools are able to do so, the error must be somewhere in your code, right?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @GazTheDestroyer you want to make sure the control template has been applied before trying to use VisualTreeHelper. Try:

```
public void EnumVisual(Visual myVisual)
{
    if(myVisual is FrameworkElement)
        ((FrameworkElement)myVisual).ApplyTemplate();

    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(myVisual); i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        Visual childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myVisual, i);

        Button _button = childVisual as Button;
        if (_button != null)
        {
            Class_Button _newButtonClass = new Class_Button();
            if (_button.Name != null)
            {
                _newButtonClass.ButtonName = _button.Name; 
            }
            ButtonsList.Add(_newButtonClass);
        }

        // Enumerate children of the child visual object.
        EnumVisual(childVisual);

    }
}
```